# Easily copy all saved data to PlayStation Plus?

Tags: ps3, playstation-plus

I've got nearly 20 folders in my PS3 Saved Data Utility, many of those having 4 items or more in them.  I want to copy them to PlayStation Plus, but can't seem to find a way to do them all at once.

It appears that, at the very least, I have to go into each individual folder and select all the items to be copied over in one batch - one folder at a time.  However, for data flagged as "Copy Prohibited", it seems the "Copy Multiple" function isn't available at all.

So, my question has two parts really:

1. Is there any way to copy multiple "Copy Protected" items to PlayStation Plus?
2. Is there a way to copy *all* of my data ("Copy Protected" or not) to PlayStation Plus in one batch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a Copy Multiple option that lets you select all content period. Just hit Square to change the sorting; you can sort by game title (stuff appears in folders) or by all. When not sorted by all you can use Copy Multiple to select all data at once rather than going through each folder.

Best I can tell this copies everything, at least in the PS3 Data Utility. I don't believe there's any way to copy PS2/1 saved data this way if that's what you mean by Copy Protected stuff.

The easy way to do this for new titles is to set them up to automatically copy content to online storage. What I did was run through all of my games and launch them once. When you first launch a game after getting the ability to auto-upload, you'll be asked if you want to auto-upload saved data for that game. Repeat for all games you own/want to keep backups of. For older data I'm not sure if this works, so just copy over all saves using the above method to be sure the first time.

Comment: In my case, "Copy Protected" items include all data from Mass Effect, some data from Mass Effect 2 (both are off-the-shelf games for PS3), and data for Sonic The Hedgehog 4 and YouTube.  The rest of my data (nearly 20 folders) is not protected.

Comment: @Iszi really? My ME3 and Sonic 4 data copied over. Is the data from your PSN account?

Comment: I'm always logged into PSN when my PS3 is on.  I'm not sure what you mean by "from your PSN account".  This is the only PS3 I've ever had an account on - I've never transferred save data via PSN or PS+ until now.

Comment: Also, I used your suggestion to dump my data that isn't "Copy Prohibited" to a USB drive.  Worked like a charm, but I still couldn't select the "Copy Prohibited" data for a Copy Multiple operation - even if I wanted to just upload it to PS+.

Comment: @Iszi strange, I have no idea how to help you there...we have some of the same games but I never got any copy prohibited problem

Comment: When I try to use "copy multiple" and then "select all" it only selects 269 of 326 saves. I guess the others are protected. I want to save all to the online storage, so I don't see why I can't select all. If I change sorting from "all" to "by title" I will still have to select and copy each one individually. Is this the only way?

Comment: @DominicDeCoco dunno, but some saves I think are copy protected and can't be moved at all, I think Killzone 2 is this. I think Sony eventually stopped this with cloud saves being a thing, but some older titles may still have it